# Team Foundation Power Tools, tfpt from Command Prompt causing "access denied"?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, tfs-power-tools

I'm using visual studio 2013 and tfs 2012 on my project, what i wanted to do is Unshelve shelveset created from one branch to another. I followed this [tutorial](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/06/06/unshelve-shelveset-created-from-one-branch-to-another.aspx), and downloaded Team Foundation Power Tools 2013 [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f). After i install the software whenever i go to cmd and type tfpt it will produce error :

**tfpt.exe is not a valid Win32 application.** followed by **Access Denied** in Command Prompt

What is causing this problem or any idea why this is happen ?

Comment: "tfpt.exe is not a valid Win32 application" suggests that your installation is corrupted. Have you tried repairing the install?

Comment: Yes, i already try repair and also redownload the file but the problem still exist. I also tried to ask my friends to do the exact same thing, what strange is one of my friend success but the other one get the same problem as mine.